# Two main() in different source files under same project

Tags: c, eclipse, program-entry-point

Hey guys can we use two or more `main()` in different C source files under same project in eclipse? What am I actually trying is to write a server and a client source file under same project with main() in each of it. I am getting an error `main() redeclaration`. is there any way to do this? If yes please tell me how to run that successfully in eclipse CDT Kepler. Regards,

Comment: Make sure the two `main` functions are defined in different modules and those modules are not linked together by the build system.

Comment: What's your OS, and development environment ?

Comment: It can't be accomplished relatively easy in c++ with namespaces, in c it is much more complicated

Comment: A simple way if you don't have a better way in your build system: put both `main`s in a ifdef guard: `#ifdef MYMAIN1` ... `#endif` and `#ifdef MYMAIN2` ... `#endif` then build with either `-DMYMAIN1` or `-DMYMAIN2` switches (this is the gcc syntax) for example

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I am new to Eclipse. Can you please be more clear Mr.Larsmans? Thank you!

Comment: Mine is windows 7 Eclipse CDT - SirDarius

Comment: if you finally link them together, you can not

Comment: Is your question about Eclipse in particular? If so, please add the `eclipse` tag to your question. My answers are for the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also *simulate* having two `main` functions in the same project by having `main` call either `mainClient` or `mainServer` (your two main functions renamed) depending on a condition of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have ton include each one selectively when linking your two programs.

A build system (Makefile, IDE…) helps.

#### Example

If you have these source files:

Client only:

- main-client.c
- source1-client.c

Server only:

- main-server.c
- source1-server.c

Common sources:

- source1-common.c
- source2-common.c
- source3-common.c

Then a simple (stupid) Makefile is:

```
all: client server

client:
    gcc -o client main-client.c source1-client.c source1-common.c source2-common.c source3-common.c

server:
    gcc -o server main-server.c source1-server.c source1-common.c source2-common.c source3-common.c
```

Comment: I have one server.c and client.c but no common.c. Please spare me!

Comment: You can safely ignore them ;) Someone else might find them helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys we can actually do it by following what Simon and Brandin suggested. Also see this example if anyone still have doubts. Thankyou! 
`#define my main()` 
`my()` `{` 
`printf("hello frnz");` 
`}`
 So we can have as many mains as we wish. Vola